# Attach click function to the button inside a popup in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup, jquery, button

I'm trying to create a button inside a popup which will draw a line on the map when clicked. Line coordinates must be based on the properties of the point layer.

I saw some ansewrs on stack and it should look like this http://jsfiddle.net/cfsg6t7u/ but the coords are hardocded and it should be based on the point layer data.

In my code buttons make no action. Here is my HTML file with js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>test</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./points.js"></script>
    
            <style>
                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                #map {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id='map'></div>
    
            <script>
                var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5)
                var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    
                var pointsLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
                    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                        var content = feature.properties.name;
                        content += "<br><button id='draw" + feature.properties.name + "'>draw a line</btn>";
                        
                        $("#draw" + feature.properties.name).click(function() {
                        var line = L.polyline([[latlng.lat, 0], [latlng.lng, 360]])
                        });
    
                        return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(content);
                }})
                
                pointsLayer.addTo(map);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is another version of adding clickable button but it gives an html object:

```
var pointsLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

                return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(feature.properties.name + '<br>' +
                 $("<button id='draw" + feature.properties.name + "'>draw a line</button>").click(function() {
                var line = L.polyline([[latlng.lat, 0], [latlng.lng, 360]]);
                })[0]);
        }})
```

Here is sample points.js data:

```
    var points = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
                                                                                                                                  
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "pierwszy"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "drugi"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 5 ] } },
]}
```

I know Leaflet and JS as little as it works enough to aim my goal.

**EDIT**:

Because this question got a lot of views here is my final map with buttons I wanted to create. Maybe it will be helpful to see the result for people who want to achieve similar effect.
https://marylagis.github.io/webmaps/citiesonlines/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to draw line between the two points in GeoJSON?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963988/add-button-in-leaflet-popup

Comment: @TomazicM I want to draw a line between a point in geojson and a point created on the fly partially based on this point coords in geojson. I couldn't figure out how to make click function working properly. Bernd Loigge answered me below. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: If his answer helped you solve your problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to accept it, to let other people know that problem was resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use jQuery here IMHO. You can pass an `HTMLElement` to the bindPopup function. So just create a `div` and the `button` as javascript objects and construct the container that way. Then you can add an `onclick` function to the button where you can access the `latlng` or the whole `feature`.

Working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc1twzpd/1/).

```js
const points = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },

  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "pierwszy"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "drugi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 5]
      }
    },
  ]
}
const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);
const osm = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

const pointsLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
  pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `<br>${feature.properties.name}<br>`;

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Create Line";

    button.onclick = function() {
      const line = L.polyline([latlng, [10, 5]]);
      line.addTo(map);
    }

    div.appendChild(button);

    return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(div);
  }
});

pointsLayer.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just saw jQuery in others answers on stack so tried to use it as well.

In another attempt I tried to create div, then button and combine it together but still button wasn't working and I was focused on using jQuery thinking it will be easier.